# Contribution Status Updates, no more 'overdue'

Tags: civicontribute

I've been trying to follow the contribution status updates and found this link very helpful: http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRM/CiviAccounts+Data+Flow#CiviAccountsDataFlow-Otherchangestocontributionstatus

I have a follow up question/thought. The 'overdue' status is no longer an option for contributions. We had been using this in the case that a donor who had previously indicated they would mail in a check, or the like, never did. We give is a 90 day grace period but then change the status to overdue. (Although we like the language 'expired' better when talking to donors.) We like that this is a separate status than 'cancelled'. In our workflow they represent two different concepts. This is especially helpful when it comes to talking to the owners of PCPs - we can easily see if we cancelled a donation (something we removed due to an error or request) vs a pending donation that simply never came in.

How hard (or crazy) would it be for me to add a custom contribution status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the contribution status itself is pretty easy. You can do that with Administer/System Settings/Option Groups, find the one for Contribution Status and click on 'options'. You will then get the possibility to add a value.

This is just adding a status, so I assume the settings of the status will be done manually. If you want to automate that you will have to develop a small extension that acts when a contribution is added or changed, and sets your status in relevant cases.

Am I making sense?

Comment: Oh my, is it really that easy? Feel a little dumb I didn't know where these options were, thanks a bunch!

Comment: Normally, options really are this easy.  Unfortunately, this one is a special case, and it won't let you change contribution statuses.  There are too many accounting things related to it.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you can set new options in Administer > System Settings > Option Groups, but you'll notice that it says:

> This option group is reserved for system use. You cannot add or delete options in this list.

You could work around it by adding a new item in the civicrm_option_value table, but you'd be definitely doing something that CiviCRM is telling you not to do.  You may have upgrade problems at some later point, because CiviCRM will assume nobody has gone in and messed around with those options.

Instead, you might consider that there really is no *new* data to be stored; you just want to be able to find really old pending contributions.  If you just create a report based upon the donor detail report with the following changes, you ought to be able to find the right folks:

- Contribution Status set to Pending, Cancelled, or whatever else
- Receive date set to "To end of previous quarter" or an equivalent relative date (I know it's not exactly what you want, but date filters will be improving soon, I hear)

You can even set this as a dashlet so that the person in charge of pestering people about this can have it on his or her dashboard.

Comment: In previous versions you could add to that options set (I have on old install I'm working on upgrading at the moment). In the current version you can at least change how the statuses read - which will do what we need.